# flowExecutionUrl no redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I've followed some examples for redirecting in SWF and every do it equal. In my case the link don't redirect, execution reference don't change and url has changed to href's value. If I set it in a commandButton then the result is succes.

I use JSF 2.2 and SWF 2.3 on glassfish 4. Any suggestions> Thanks!

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&amp;_eventId=TRANSITION_NAME" >
```

**My link**

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&amp;_eventId=visit" >
```

**URL result**

```
http://localhost:8080/aio/spring/adminSpace?execution=e4s3&_eventId=visit
```

**Flow definition**

```
<view-state id="showEvent" view="list_events.xhtml">
         <secured attributes="ROLE_MEMBER" />

         <on-entry>
             <evaluate expression="eventProvider.showEvents()" result="viewScope.pagesList"/>
         </on-entry>

         <transition on="pageCreated" to="newEvent" />
         <transition on="visit" to="visitEvent"/>

    </view-state>

        <view-state id="newEvent" view="newEvent_1.xhtml">
            <secured attributes="ROLE_MEMBER" />

            <on-render>
                <set name="pictureProvider.idRequest" value="'event'" />
            </on-render>

            <transition on="back" to="showEvent" />
            <transition on="save" to="showEvent" />

            <on-exit>
                <evaluate expression="eventProvider.deleteTempComponents()" />
            </on-exit>
        </view-state>

        <view-state id="visitEvent" view="event.xhtml">

        </view-state>
```

**WebFlowConfig class**

```
@Configuration
 public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFacesFlowConfiguration {


@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
            .addFlowExecutionListener(new FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener())
            .addFlowExecutionListener(new SecurityFlowExecutionListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            //.setViewFactoryCreator(new JsfViewFactoryCreator())
            .setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
}



 @Bean
 public CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
     Map<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

     scopes.put("view", new ViewScope());
     CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
     configurer.setScopes(scopes);

     return configurer;
 }
```

}

**WebMvcConfig class**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping mapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(1);
    mapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
    /* If no flow matches, map the path to a view, e.g. "/intro" maps to a view named "intro" */
    mapping.setDefaultHandler(new UrlFilenameViewController());
    return mapping;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    JsfFlowHandlerAdapter adapter = new JsfFlowHandlerAdapter();
    adapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver faceletsViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter simpleControllerHandlerAdapter() {
    return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
}

@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver=new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es"));

    return localeResolver;
}

 @Bean
 public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msg=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
     msg.setBasename("classpath*:error");

     return msg;
 }

 @Bean
 public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
     return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
 }



 /*
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor changeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    changeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");

    return changeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping nameHandlerMapping(){
    ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping controller=new ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping();
    Object[] obj={localeChangeInterceptor()};

    controller.setInterceptors(obj);

    return controller;

}*/
```

}

Comment: What is the HTTP status when you click on the link? Also make sure view="event.xhtml" is actually mapping to a valid view

Comment: Finally, I decided to use JSF buttons but honestly I don't like this way. I still look for a solution because I don't understand why it stays in the same view.

HTTP status is 200 and view is well defined because for buttons I use the same data.

Comment: Update: I found on Spring forums that eventId attr is not checked by JSF 2 so it's neccessary to create a custom flow adapter. They show a example of a right implementation but unfortunately doesn't work in my project.